# How do I call the UrlCanonicalize API function correctly?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HRESULT UrlCanonicalize(
  _In_     PCTSTR pszUrl,
  _Out_    PTSTR pszCanonicalized,
  _Inout_  DWORD *pcchCanonicalized,
  DWORD dwFlags
);
```

**Example:**

```
LPCTSTR pszURL  = URL.c_str();
LPSTR pszOutPut = new CHAR[ strUrl.length ];
DWORD* dwCount = new DWORD[  strUrl.length ];
hRes =  UrlCanonicalize( pszURL, pszOutPut,dwCount, URL_ESCAPE_UNSAFE );
```

**Output:**

```
E_INVALIDARG
```

This API fails and returns `E_INVALIDARG` every time I try to call it. Please give me a working code snippet to call the `UrlCanonicalize` function.

Comment: Why don't you show fist what you tried?

Comment: @MariusBancila-> Can u give a code snippet for this function?

Comment: It would be far more educational for you to show us what code you've tried. That way, we can tell you *why* it didn't work and how to fix it. You cannot learn anything by copying-and-pasting other people's code.

Comment: @CodyGray-> I have updated the question with my try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the C++ language, [the SDK documentation for the function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773768.aspx) pretty much tells you everything that you need to know:

- You pass it a C-style nul-terminated string that contains your URL.
- You pass it pointer to a buffer to receive the output string.
- You pass it one or more flags that customize the function's behavior.
- And finally, it returns to you an `HRESULT` value, which is an error code. If it succeeds, that value will be `S_OK`. If it fails, it will be some other error code.

It works like this:

```
std::wstring originalURL(L"http://www.example.com/hello/cruel/../world/");

// Allocate a buffer of the appropriate length.
// It needs to be at least as long as the input string.
std::wstring canonicalURL(originalURL.length() + 1, L'\0');
DWORD length = originalURL.length() + 1;

// Call the function to modify the string.
HRESULT hr = UrlCanonicalize(originalURL.c_str(), // input string
                             &canonicalURL[0],    // buffer
                             &length,             // pointer to a DWORD that contains the length of the buffer
                             URL_UNESCAPE | URL_ESCAPE_UNSAFE);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // The function succeeded.
    // Your canonicalized URL is in the canonicalURL string.
    MessageBox(nullptr, canonicalURL.c_str(), L"The URL is:", MB_OK);   
}
else
{
    // The function failed.
    // The hr variable contains the error code.
    throw std::runtime_error("The UrlCanonicalize function failed.");
}
```

If you want to make sure that the buffer is sufficiently long (and avoid having to handle that error), use the constant `INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH` (declared in `WinInet.h`) when allocating it:

```
std::wstring canonicalURL(INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH, L'\0');
DWORD length = INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH;
```

---

The code you tried has a couple of problems:

1. You've incorrectly initialized the `dwCount` variable. The function wants a pointer, but that doesn't mean you should declare the variable as a pointer. Nor do you want an array; this is a single `DWORD` value. So you need to declare it as a regular `DWORD`, and then use the address-of operator (`&`) to pass the function a pointer to that variable. Right now, you're passing the function garbage, so it's failing.
2. You're using C-style strings, which you should avoid in C++ code. Use the C++ string class (`std::wstring` for Windows code), which is exception safe and manages memory for you. As you already know, the `c_str()` member function gives you easy access to a C-style nul-terminated string like all C APIs want. This works fine, you do not need to use raw character arrays yourself. Avoid `new` whenever possible.

Potentially, a third problem is that you're trying to use the C++ string type `std::string` instead of `std::wstring`. The former is an 8-bit string type and doesn't support Unicode in a Windows environment. You want `std::wstring`, which is a wide string with Unicode support. It's what all the Windows API functions expect if you have the `UNICODE` symbol defined for your project (which it is by default).

Comment: I have a small problem with the above solution, my url is not encoded after UrlCanonicalize api call

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
LPCTSTR pszURL = URL.c_str();
DWORD nOutputLength = strUrl.length * 2 + 32;
LPTSTR pszOutPut = new TCHAR[nOutputLength];
hRes = UrlCanonicalize( pszURL, pszOutPut, &nOutputLength, URL_ESCAPE_UNSAFE);
```

On the third parameter you provided garbage instead of pointer to initialized value, so you had API failure back. MSDN [has it all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for you:

> A pointer to a value that, on entry, is set to the number of characters in the pszCanonicalized buffer.